# clangd LSP server not recognizing 'memory' file

Tags: c++, error-handling, emacs, clangd

I'm working on a c++ project and use the clangd LSP server in Spacemacs. The first line of the file I'm working on says `#include "somefile.hpp"`

The lsp server gives the error message

*In included file: 'memory' file not found [pp_file_not_found]. Too many errors emitted, stopping now [fatal_too_many_errors]*

It probably has nothing to do with "some file.hpp" itself but is more of a fundamental problem. I have no idea how to approach this problem. Thanks in advance!